# How to return field names in correct case

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I had the need to include in one of my system's DQL queries, a subquery with LIMIT clause. As Doctrine doesn't support it, I changed it to a native query. Yet the native query is returning lower case fields instead of the correct case.
The case is that as this is working code, I had some views depending on this names and it's much harder to change all names.

But I found here http://bit.ly/1Ht1ojH, that this aspect can be configured in Doctrine. So I tried this code:

```
$conn = $this->getConnection();
$conn->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_FIELD_CASE, CASE_NATURAL);
$res = $conn->query("select MyCasedField from whatever")->fetchAll();
```

Yet I'm getting the error "Attempted to call method "setAttribute" on class "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager".

I tried with manager also with same result.

Now I now I can make some code to translate the fields, but I find that the configure solution to be much more clean.

Someone knows why symfony doesn't let me configure the connection ?

Also if there is any way of using LIMIT in a DQL's subquery I would find it better.

Comment: This doesn't help you directly, I know, but the last time I ran into the "no LIMIT in DQL for a subquery" problem I actually re-modeled the database. To me that was the lesser of two evils when compared to falling-back on a native query.

Comment: Actually I don't have problems in using native queries. I think it's an illusion try to write a database independent application. You allways be better using the full power of a database instead of using a feature's subset that it's available cross-databases.

Comment: Oh, I don't mean that from "db independence" perspective, but rather from an ORM-adherence perspective. Once you invoke a single native query, you've introduced transactions against your data-model that can't be tracked with the mapping data. If you stick with the entities then changes can be identified with the schema tool and unit-tested against.

It's not a "never-do" scenario for me, but it definitely introduces a bit of maintenance risk so I always think twice before going down that road.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `LIMIT` keyword in DQL. To use this functionality you can call method `setMaxResults($limit)` on your query object. It is also can be applied to Query Builder.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT p FROM Product p')
        ->setMaxResults($limit);
```

Comment: I know. I you read the initial part of my question, I wrote that Doctrine doesn't support it. What I would need is a limit solution for a subquery, not for the main query.